# Tcp Client with multiple string

Tags: c#, windows, forms, tcp, client

I want to design a tcp client which sends four strings to server . And I want to receive four  strings from server . Then later I have to split the received four strings based on the command Id. I need help in designing a client with the above function.

```
string 2 = 02, false , fail.
string 3 = 03, 1.5,6.5,000,start.
string 4 = 04,1000,1000,100,start.
I want to send string with this format. In the above format of the strings , 01,02,03 and 04 are the command ids. I will split the string based on the command id and i will use it in the corresponding function.
```

Comment: The simple solution is to add a "\n" to each string so you can split around the return on the receive end.

Answer (score 0):

A easy way is that put a `int len` before every string.

You can add all string to one. The format will be like below

length of string 1 | string 1 | length of string 2 | string 2|....

When server receives the message, first read the length of string 1, and then read the string 1 with this length, and the others are parsed one by one.

Comment: i am sorry i can't understand . i am a budding developer in c#.  can you say me in detail. int len incase?

Comment: OK, I'll edit my answer and give you a little example.

Comment: It means that i have to split the receiving string with the length of the string . But what if I get each strings at different time . Because I am very sure that my server won't send all the four strings into a single string. Server will send each string at different time based on  what type of string function it required.

Comment: And i should send string from my client one by one . I am not allowed to send all four into single string. For example. If function 1 selected, my client should send string 1 to server. If function 2 selected , my client should send  string 2 to server. If function 1 and 2 get selected , my client should send string 1 and string 2 to server. If function 1,2,3 and 4 selected , my client should send all 4 strings to server.

Comment: It's ok to send one by one.